# 1406クエリエラー と 1265クエリエラー について

Tags: mysql

**既にレコードが存在しているVARCHAR型カラムに対して、(既存データの最長に合わせ)長さを出来るだけ短くしたい**
カラムの長さを変更するSQLを実行した場合、既に存在しているレコードの長さ以上の長さを指定すると、エラーで弾かれる(既存レコードには影響がない)と思っていました。

下記は理解できるのですが、

```
ALTER TABLE `テーブル名` CHANGE `旧カラム名` `新カラム名` VARCHAR(5) 
クエリエラー:
#1406 - Data too long for column 'カラム名' at row 1
```

下記のようなケースになることがある理由が分かりません

```
ALTER TABLE `テーブル名` CHANGE `旧カラム名` `新カラム名` VARCHAR(50) 
クエリエラー:
#1265 - 列 'カラム名' の 行 16 でデータが切り捨てられました。
```

---

**質問**

- Q1.「ALTER TABLE `テーブル名` CHANGE」を実行した際、カラムの長さ指定が異なるだけで、「1406エラー」となったり「1265エラー」となる理由は何ですか？
- Q2.「1265エラー」の「データが切り捨てられました」の意味は？
  既存データの一部が削除された？
  それとも「データが切り捨てられました」と表示されても、データ自体はどの部分も削除されるわけではない？

---

**その他**

SQLはphpMyAdmin経由で実行しています

MySQL5.7

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: Q2 は実際の環境での実行結果を確認することで答えが分かりませんか？

Comment: 上記2つのSQLについてですが、全く同じ環境、セッション、DB、フィールドで実行されていますか？それともどこか違うところはありますか？

Comment: 全く同じ環境、セッション、DB、フィールドで実行しています。異なる点は、VARCHAR()の長さだけです

Comment: 一般的にはSTRICT_TRANS_TABLESが影響しており、設定していると1406がエラーで処理されず、設定していないと処理されるものの1265のワーニングが発生するという認識なんですが。全く同じsql_modeでセッション中も変更していないのですよね？SessionのSQLモードの確認は`SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;`です

Comment: セッション中にsql_modeを変更していません。「SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;」実行してみましたが、「SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;」と結果は同じでした